# How do I make python type something one number or letter at a time, or on a delayed pace?

Tags: python

Ok this is going to be hard to ask/explain but bear with me.
Im trying to just make things look cool when I use the while True command.
What I am trying to do Is make it type stuff slower or one letter at a time.
For example, here is my code.

```
while True:
    print ("010101010101010101010101010101")
    print ("010101010101001010101010101010")
    print ("010101010101010101010101010101")
```

When I do that it obviously rapidly repeats the commands I entered in the file. 
I am aware there is the following, 
import time
time.sleep(5)

But I wan't it to type it one at a time, not on a 5 second relay.
I hope you can understand what I am trying to ask. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: You can have a timeout of fewer than five seconds, if you like!

Comment: No I don't want it on a timer, I want it to go and type one letter at a time. Not one line at a time.

Comment: Cyber, thanks for the link I found the answer there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility:

```
import sys
import time

def cool_print(str):
  for char in str:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.05)   # Or whatever delay you'd like
  print   # One last print to make sure that you move to a new line
```

Then instead of `print ("010101010101010101010101010101")`, you'd use `cool_print("010101010101010101010101010101")`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a delay between each actual character, so you need to call `sleep` in between each one:

```
import time
while True:
    for binary_char in "10101010101010101":
        time.sleep(5) # Replace this with a much smaller number, probably
        print binary_char, # Remove trailing comma to print each character on new line
```

Comment: time is not defined :O

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming that you imported `time` since you mentioned it in the question.  I've edited my answer to include it.